# Difference between pointer initializations

Tags: c++, pointers

While I was reading C++ Primer, found this example that i don't understand

```
double dval;
double *pd = &dval; //ok:initializer is the address of a double
double *pd2 = pd; // ok:initializer is a pointer to double
```

Shouldn't `*pd2` be a pointer to pointer since `*pd` is a pointer aswell? Could somebody explain what happens in the background with the memory addresses( what is assigned to `pd2`)?

Comment: address of x == pointer to x

Comment: `*pd` is not a pointer. `*pd` is an expression of type `double`. `pd` is a pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Shouldn't `*pd2` be a pointer to pointer since `*pd` is a pointer aswell?

No.  `pd2` is being assigned the value that `pd` is currently holding.  Thus `pd2` ends up pointing at `dval`.  You would only use a pointer-to-pointer if you want `pd2` to point at `pd` itself, not what `pd` is pointing at, eg:

```
double dval;
double *pd = &dval;
double **pd2 = &pd;
```

> Could somebody explain what happens in the background with the memory addresses( what is assigned to pd2)?

A pointer is just a number that happens to be a memory address.  If you think of pointers as integers, the code you provided is not much different than the following behind the scenes:

```
double dval;
uintptr_t pd = address of dval;
uintptr_t pd2 = pd;
```

You are just assigning one pointer value (a number) as-is to another pointer (number) variable.

Answer (score 1):

The value of `pd2` is what is assigned to it,  that is the address of `dval`, which was stored as value of `pd` and assigned to the former.

Answer (score 1):

A pointer is a memory address. `double *pd2 = pd;` assigns one pointer to another pointer. No magic, just a simple assignment operation. Both pointers are pointing at the same memory address.

The value in `pd2` is the same value as in `pd`. if you were to dereference either `pd` or `pd2` you would get the value stored in `dval`.

Assigning `&pd` would require a pointer to a pointer since you are taking the address of a pointer.

Answer (score 0):

First you declare a double `dval`, then you declare a pointer, that points on that double (because its set by the doubles adress `&dval`).
Then the second pointer is set equal to the first pointer.
So finally, you have:

```
pd = pd2 = &dval
```

Which are two pointers, pointing to the same adress, **not** a pointer pointing to another pointer.